# Leaflet/Mapbox error - "Cannot read property 'minZoom' of undefined"

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I'm creating a map using leaflet with the following code:

```
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.##MY TOKEN HERE##';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets');
map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();
map.setView(new L.LatLng(32.75, -97.33), 10);
```

But when the page loads, I get a console error of

> Cannot read property 'minZoom' of undefined

This error originates from the line that says:

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets');
```

I've tried to set the minZoom value after the map variable is declared, but it doesn't work b/c by that point the error has already occurred.  I've already tried to set the setView in the same map declaration line, but it didn't help either.

Has anybody ran across this error before?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

`var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets').setView([0, 0], 2);`

source: [Mapbox blog](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/mapbox-js-with-leaflet/)

Answer (score 0):

Since it can't read the property, it looks like it's having problems finding a `<div>` with an id of `map`.

In your HTML page, try adding `<div id="map"></div>` in the body where you want your map to appear.